# how does FRP (Factory Reset Protection) work?

Tags: android, recovery, rom

In galaxy 6 EDGE+ when i'm trying to flash a custom rom, it get block by FRP [img attached], my question is how does it work? and if i can create one like that for my custom ROM?[FRP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCp9U.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this link http://support.sprint.com/support/tutorial/Turn-Factory-Reset-Protection-on-or-off-Samsung-Galaxy-S6-edge-64GB/WScenario_542_60957_771_en_1998-dvc9420001prd There is probably a better way to do this but I don't know it :(